# Is it possible to record uncompressed or > 150000 kb/S video on a smartphone or tablet?

Tags: video, ios, tablet

Is it possible to record uncompressed or > 150000 kb/S video on a smartphone or tablet?

If so, how and what devices are compatible? I am able to do this with cheap logitech webcams, however the best I was able to get with multiple smartphones/tablets was with a Moto G, which recorded compressed (mp4) video at 50000 Kb/S using UHD.

Intuitively, I expected to get higher quality video from smartphones and tablets. Am I missing something?